# Div expand reaching all edges at once

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a non-centered element wich somehow (using CSS or JS) expand to the full page reaching all the edges at the same time.

The div will be empty (just with a background or something like that, in fact is not mandatory to be a div, could be any other element that can looks like a box) and CSS3 or HTML5 can be used. Im not using jQuery, but if anyone finds a way to solve this problem using it, no problem.

At the moment my best attempt is this one: http://jsfiddle.net/ApKEu/

CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 20px;
}

.box:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all 3000ms;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
}
```

And then just create the div in the HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

But the box dont reach all the edges at the same time :(

Sorry my english and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/jTFwB/

```
$(".box").bind("mouseover", function() {
    var n = $(this).clone();
    var of = $(this).position();
    n.css({
        position:'absolute', 
        top: of.top, 
        left: of.left, 
        margin: 0
    }).appendTo("body")
    .animate({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        position: 'relative'
    });

    n.bind("mouseout", function() {
        $(this).stop(true).remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand what you want, but there are several points that I can advise.

1. You need to specify width and height of `<html>`, `<body>` to expand your box to edges of screen.

   body, html {
       width:100%;
       height: 100%;
   }
2. To expand to edge of screen, you can't scale double. It'll be larger than edge of screen.

   .box:hover {
       -webkit-transition: all 3000ms;
       left: 10%;
       top: 10%;
       height: 80%;
       width: 80%;
   }

See what I tricked on your example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Uhj5x/1/)

Answer (score 0):

what if to try this for hovered box:

```
.box:hover {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0
}
```